# Different Text area for each row

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I am working with PHP and I am able to gather the info of my database table and show it into my webpage.

For each row I am displaying a button which leads to a modal popup with a textarea containing a WYSIWYG ( I used TinyMCE ) so that I can add Details about that specific row.

This works just with 1 row when I am using this script

This is my script:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE mytalbename SET details='$_POST[textarea]' WHERE id=44");
}
?>
```

**My problem is:** how to extend this concept to all the rows in the way that each row has a button. Each button leads to a modal popup with a text area. From each text area I can modify the column "details" referring to that specific row.

And this is the code of the text area into the Form

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="" method="post" name="savechanges">
        <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savechanges"> Save changes</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here I display the button:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm get_info2' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2' name='job_id' value='[$job_id]'>Add Details</a>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm get_info3' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal3' name='job_id' value='[$job_id]'>View Details</a>
```

I Attach picture:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EROrO.png)

[Modal popup with textarea][2]

----UPDATE 1 ----

```
$results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='$_POST[textarea]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'" );
```

and

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="" method="post" name="savechanges">
        <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savechanges"> Save changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value=" . $row['id'] . ">
    </form>
</div>
```

-----------Update 2---------------

```
  <?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {

    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='$_POST[textarea]' WHERE id='44'" );

}

?>
```

----------------UPDATE 3--------------------

```
          <div class="modal-body info_data2">
                <form action="" method="post" name="savechanges">
                   <textarea name="textarea">    </textarea>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savechanges"> Save changes</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">                                           
                </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div></div></div></div>    </div>    

<?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='".$_POST['textarea']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['hidden']);
}
?>
```

---------------UPDATE 4 ------------ ALL CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' }); tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();</script>
</head> 
<body>
  <!--  ------SCRIPT that fetch data from database and show table-->
       <?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');}
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");

}           

$sql = "SELECT * from job";
if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');}
echo "
    <table class='table'>
    <thead>
    <tr>";
    /* Get field information for all columns */
    while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "
    <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>"; }
    echo " </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>";
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $job_id = $row['id'];
    echo "<form action='' method=post>";
    echo "<tr class='info'>
                <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>
                <td>
                <select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
                    <option value='new' ". ($row['status'] == 'new'? 'selected ': '') .">New</option>
                    <option value='progress' ". ($row['status'] == 'progress'? 'selected ': '') .">Progress</option>
                    <option  value='wait' ". ($row['status'] == 'wait'? 'selected ': '') .">Wait</option>
                    <option value='done' ". ($row['status'] == 'done'? 'selected ': '') .">Done</option>
                    <option value='close' ". ($row['status'] == 'close'? 'selected ': '') .">Close</option>
                </select>
                </td>                                                                                                                     
                <td>  
                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='update'>Update</button>
                </td>
                <td> 
                <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm get_info'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' name='job_id'  value= '[$job_id]'>Customer Info</a>
                <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm get_info2'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2' name='job_id'  value= '[$job_id]'>Add Details</a>
                </td> 
                </tr>"; 
                echo "</form>";  }
                echo " 
                </tbody>
                </table>";
                ?>

<!--  ------SCRIPT FOR BUTTON "CUSTOMER INFO"-->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.get_info').click(function(){
        var job_id = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name=hidden]').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'responses.php',
          data: 'job_id=' + job_id,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            $('.info_data').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <!-- MODAL THAT SHOW UP AFTER CLICKING ON "CUSTOMER INFO"-->
  <div class="container">
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                      <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Information</h4>
                      </div>                       
                     <div class="modal-body info_data">
                      </div>
                     <div class="modal-footer">
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                      </div>    
                      </div>  
                      </div> 
                      </div>
                      </div>

<!--  ---SCRIPT FOR BUTTON  "ADD DETAILS"  -->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.get_info2').click(function(){
        var job_id = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name=hidden]').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'responses2.php',
          data: 'job_id=' + job_id,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            $('.info_data2').html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

 <!-- MODAL THAT SHOW UP AFTER CLICKING BUTTON  "ADD DETAILS" 
which allow you to send data to database through the text area -->      
<div class="container"> 
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
                 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Add Job Details</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body info_data2">
                <form action="" method="post" name="savechanges">
                   <textarea name="textarea">    </textarea>
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savechanges"> Save changes</button>
                   <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">

                </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div> 
                </div> 
                </div> 
                </div>
                </div>

<!--  SCRIPT THAT SHOULD be able to send what is written in the text area to the database,-->


<?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='".$_POST['textarea']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['hidden']);
}
?>

  </body>
</html>
```

--------------------UPDATE 5 ------------------

SECTION 1

PHP code that fetch data from the table JOB
and show for each row 3 button:

- update button for updating the status and the priority
- customer info button (fetch data from table "customer")
- add details button (send information with through a modal pop up with a wusiwug to the column "details of the table JOB")
- view details button: fetch data from the column "details of the table JOB"

SECTION 2:

SCRIPT FOR BUTTON "CUSTOMER INFO"

SECTION 3:

MODAL THAT SHOW UP AFTER CLICKING ON "CUSTOMER INFO"

SECTION 3:

SCRIPT FOR BUTTON  "ADD DETAILS"

SECTION 4:
 MODAL THAT SHOW UP AFTER CLICKING BUTTON  "ADD DETAILS" 
which allow you to send data to database through the text area

SECTION 5:
SCRIPT THAT SHOULD be able to send what is written in the text area to the database

[OVERVIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EROrO.png)

Comment: I read this 4 times and I still can't understand what you're asking.  Can you clarify please.

Comment: ...I have and it's NOT a good idea and will require some doing and no idea why you'd want to do that.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Could yo clarify what is not a good idea?

Comment: Because, you're going to have a whale of a time querying later for any of MySQL's functions. Try and think ahead here, and you'll see what I mean (always think of the future and ahead of time).

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup - I tried to clarify.

Comment: @Fred -ii- , what is important for me is to understand how to do that, I thank you anyway for your tips. Good one, but not solving my problem now.

Comment: I'm just trying to help you foresee what you stand at getting yourself into, and possibly save you a lot of work down the road. If and when that happens, you'll thank me for me it (probably). I wish you well with this.

Comment: Oh I think I get it, and it's not that bad at all.  Just pass the ID of the row along with the text area value.  It can be a hidden input field that is passed with POST based on the ID of the button.  @Fred-ii- is over thinking this I think.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, your help is fully appreciated but can u then tell me what is the best way to go, or what would you do in this case. And to answer your first statement: I want to do this because I am creating an internal control panel for my pc-repair company. I need to have this text area so that I can write an update anytime during the process of the repairing.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup exactly, I had the feeling I had to use an hidden field. I update my question now.

Comment: @ I made an attampt in mu UPDATE 1 but I think I have made some errors in the second part

Comment: This *"My problem is how to extend this concept to all the rows in the way that each text area I am writing into is referring to that specific row."*  was your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40369776/1 --- Now you've changed that to *"My problem is how to extend this concept to all the rows in the way that each row has a button."* - My comment was based on your original post, meaning and thinking that, you wanted to enter data in that `<textarea>` and use the data to be entered into separate rows; you see what I mean? That's why your question was unclear/confusing.

Comment: ...one that I thought was a bad idea; hence, you and someone else commenting "back" at me ;-) Now it's a totally different ballgame.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I understand I was not so clear therefore I updated my question. In fact, I am able to make this work but just if I query a specific row. -( I click the button, I get the text area and what I am writing goes to the database ). My problem is that I would like to have this concept for each row. So the text area I am writing into has to be somehow connected to the ID of the row. Example: if I am modifying the row n.10 .... the text area which pops up klicking the button of the row 10, is editing only the row 10.

Comment: If I understand this correctly now, what you'd need to do is that the form needs to be set inside a loop that will allow to modify the said row(s) individually. As for the popup modal stuff, I'm not the guy for this. I rarely work clientside.

Comment: would you be against using jQuery and ajax? It would be simple work if you used that.

Comment: You will get error with this `$_POST[textarea]`. the correct form is `'$_POST["textarea"]`. also this line will not do what you want: `<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value=" . $row['id'] . ">` you have to change it to `<input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">` if theo whole block is in a `for` loop

Comment: @Icewine I agree, but I am a bit lost now. Can you point me in the right direction using ajax/jquery ?

Comment: @EhsanT -> with this code I am able to send data to the database (see my update 2), so I need only to understand how to make this work for every rows

Comment: Sorry, but your code is both very very confusing and not well formatted. You have opened 4 `<div>`s at the top of your code which you never have closed them. you have different `<input type="hidden">` elements in your code which I do not know which one of them you really want to use. and also, you really should not have more than one element with same `name` attribute in your html. so having many elements with the `name="hidden"` in you html will cause your code to malfunction. please try to practice to write your codes in a better formatted way so in future you yourself can read them!

Comment: Sorry for that, I updated the code and try to put some comments. could you please check it out if its better now? I am trying to improve because I am kind of new to php so thanks for your tips.

Comment: @MisterNubb, I really tried to understand your code and your logic, but It's very hard. I have edited my answer and did my best to break down your problems and provide some solutions to them. your code has at least 4 different sections that I can not figure how at least 3 of these 4 sections relate to each other. I hope my answer can help you to solve your problem. if not, please try to open another question, but be as clear as you can an describe your issue step by step...

Comment: Thank you for your time. I made the last attempt, updating my question with a new explanation of the sections and a picture maybe can help you more. Please have a look if you can give the last chance.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if everything is working and you just need change it to work for any record, you just need to change *44* in your *php* code with `$_POST['hidden']`

So your *html* and *php* would be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="" method="post" name="savechanges">
        <textarea name="textarea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="savechanges"> Save changes</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='".$_POST['textarea']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['hidden']);
}
?>
```

But I do encourage you to practice **mysqli parameterized query** and not using variables directly inside your queries...

---

**UPDATE**

Since your code is really hard to understand, I will just update my answer to add some assumptions, just in case they are right!

I do not know how you are showing `<div>` with the title of `<h4 class="modal-title">Add Job Details</h4>`. So let's assume that `$('.info_data2').html(data);` is doing what you want to do!

So in your JavaScript you have:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.get_info2').click(function(){
        var job_id = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name=hidden]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'responses2.php',
            data: 'job_id=' + job_id,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                $('.info_data2').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Here you are just passing `job_id` as the parameter, so in the *responses2.php* you have two issues:
1- you have to change `$_POST['hidden']` to `$_POST['job_id']`
2- you do not have any parameter for the textarea!

Then you have to change your JavaScript to something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.get_info2').click(function(){
        var job_id = $(this).parent().siblings('input[name=hidden]').val();
        var textarea = $(this).parent().siblings('[name=textarea]').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'responses2.php',
            data: { "job_id": job_id, "textarea" : textarea} ,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                $('.info_data2').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Remember, since your HTML code is really confusing, you have to work on how to get correct value of `job_id` and `textarea`. with this code I'm sure these are not returning correct values. it's just a sample of how you do what you want to do and just to put you on a correct Track!!!**

as you can see, I have have added this line: `var textarea = $(this).parent().siblings('name=textarea').val();` and also changed the `data` line to this: `data: { "job_id": job_id, "textarea" : textarea} ,` to be able to send the `textarea` value to the *responses2.php* file...

Then in *responses2.php* you have to change it like this:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['savechanges'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET details='".$_POST['textarea']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['job_id']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the last statement, I will have a look at it. I already did what you suggested but that does not work. The table does not get updated. Any control I can do?

Comment: You only have provided some parts of your code and regarding to your last comment on your question, this answer should work. but if you can put the complete code from your _html_(which shows how you generate the form) and also complete code for your _php_(which shows how your data is stored and fetched to/from the database), then I can have a more accurate answer.

Comment: I made an Update4 on my question. Thank you